# Change button color

Tags: magento2, php, module, css

I am installing an custom module from someone, but im forget which module it is, but im sure i already unninstall that module, but the button color change to green like at the picture below. How could i change it back?

[image]

Comment: did you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command

Answer (score 1):

**Now Please rename pub/static folder after use deploy command.**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: should i just run that command?

Comment: now pub inside static folder rename and use deploy command.

Comment: sorry i dont understand, which one should i rename?

Comment: magento 2 folder structure root directory pub folder inside static folder rename after use this command                                                                        php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy